# Reputation added is moved up on the Activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I just noticed that the little green-encased number in the Activity tab's Reputation pane is bumped up too far:

[image: image of the problem]

For reference, that red line is perfectly straight and used to be level across the top of the green box and the black number. The problem seems to have appeared at the same time the reputation number in usercards got darker.

I see this issue on Meta Stack Exchange and Super User, suggesting that it affects all/most/many sites.